# If $\frac{\sin^2 x}{a} = \frac{\cos^2 x}{b}$, then prove that they are also equal to $\frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $ \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{a} = \dfrac{\cos^2 x}{b}$, then prove that they are also equal to $\dfrac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{a+b}$.

I don't know how to solve this.

I was thinking about componeto dividento, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Let $\frac{sin^2 x}{a} =  \frac{cos^2 x}{b}=k$, then find sine and cosine in terms of $k$ and substitute into the required fraction to show it is also equal to $k$.

Comment: See VII: Addendo Property of  https://www.math-only-math.com/properties-of-ratio-and-proportion.html

Comment: I restored your statement about what you considered (along with making minor formatting tweaks), as the Math.SE community likes to know that questioners have given thought to their questions. (Of course, you're free to remove it again if it doesn't accurately reflect your thoughts, but if so: please tell what you know about the problem so that answerers can tailor their responses appropriately.)

Comment: Check out my question here - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/how-many-regular-mse-users-frequent-the-meta-page?noredirect=1#comment127948_29995

Comment: This is a general property of proportions, no trigonometry involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally true that $\frac a b =\frac c d$ implies $\frac a b =\frac c d=\frac {a+c} {b+d}$. For a proof let $r=\frac a b =\frac c d$, write $a=rb,c=rd$ and calculate $\frac {a+c} {b+d}$.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove a proposition in general.

> **Proposition 1**. If $a/b=c/d$ then they are also equal to $\frac{a\pm c}{b\pm d}$.

**Proof**. We know that $ad=bc$. So
$$bc=ad$$
$$ab\pm bc= ab\pm ad$$
$$(a\pm c)b=a(b\pm d)$$
$$(a\pm c)/(b\pm d)=a/b$$
Actually I wrote these equations from bottom to top, and reversed them (since it is easier that way as you can see).

Answer (score 1):

$${\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{a} = \dfrac{\cos^2 x}{b}\implies\\\dfrac{a}{\sin^2 x} = \dfrac{b}{\cos^2 x}\implies\\\dfrac{a}{\sin^2 x}+\dfrac{b}{\sin^2 x} = \dfrac{b}{\sin^2 x}+\dfrac{b}{\cos^2 x}\implies\\{a+b\over \sin^2 x}={b(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)\over \sin^2 x\cos^2 x}={b\over \sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\implies\\{a+b}={b\over \cos^2 x}\implies \\{\sin^2 x\over a}={\cos^2x\over b}={1\over a+b}={\sin^2x+\cos^2x\over a+b}}$$